# Can I do this in SQL function without a cursor?

Tags: sql-server, database-cursor

I'm working on a timesheet database.  In simple terms, the TimesheetEntries table has four columns

```
ID int (identity, 1, 1)
StaffID int
ClockedIn datetime
ClockedOut datetime
```

I've been asked to write a report to show staff attendance by date range.  The user puts in a date, and the report outputs the clocking in and out times of all attending staff members together with their duration on-site.

However, and this is where it gets tricky, staff members sometimes clock out to leave the site for short periods, and the report is required to ignore these (when they leave the site for less than 2 hours).

So, let's assume the following entries

```
ID  StaffID  ClockedIn    ClockedOut
1   4        0900         1200
2   4        1330         1730
3   5        0900         1200
4   5        1409         1730
5   4        1830         1930
```

The report's output **SHOULD** be

```
StaffID  ClockedIn    ClockedOut
4        0900         1930
5        0900         1200     
5        1409         1730
```

Is there any way of doing this without a cursor or even a cursor nested inside a cursor (which is where I'm at right now!)?  We're not talking about huge datasets here and performance isn't really an issue (it's a report, not a production system) but I really don't like cursors if I can avoid them.

Thanks

Edward

Comment: Can you show your cursor code? Maybe we can help you improve it so that you have less of a problem with using cursors in general. I think there is a pretty widespread fear/hatred of cursors and they do have their place (as I was discussing with Jeremy below). I certainly believe that your nested cursor could be accomplished without nesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the data from Jeremy's response above but went at the problem a whole different way. This uses a recursive CTE, which I think requires SQL Server 2005. It reports the results accurately (I believe) and also reports the number of clock-ins recorded during the timeframe and the total number of minutes off (can be more than 120 because the restriction is simply that each offsite period is less than two hours).

```
declare @TimeSheetEntries table 
    ( 
    ID int identity not null primary key, 
    StaffID int not null, 
    ClockedIn datetime not null, 
    ClockedOut datetime not null 
    ); 

insert into @TimeSheetEntries 
    ( 
    StaffID, 
    ClockedIn, 
    ClockedOut 
    ) 
select 
    4, 
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00', 
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00' 
union all select 
    4, 
    '2012-01-01 13:30:00', 
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00' 
union all select 
    5, 
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00', 
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00' 
union all select 
    5, 
    '2012-01-01 14:09:00', 
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00'
union all select
    4,
    '2012-01-01 18:30:00', 
    '2012-01-01 19:30:00';


WITH ClockData AS
(
    SELECT ID, StaffID, ClockedIn, ClockedOut AS EffectiveClockout, 1 AS NumClockIns, 0 AS MinutesOff
    FROM @TimeSheetEntries ts
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM @TimeSheetEntries tsWhere WHERE tsWhere.ClockedOut BETWEEN DATEADD(hour, -2, ts.ClockedIn) AND ts.ClockedIn)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cd.ID, cd.StaffID, cd.ClockedIn, ts.ClockedOut AS EffectiveClockout, cd.NumClockIns + 1 AS NumClockIns, cd.MinutesOff + DateDiff(minute, cd.EffectiveClockout, ts.ClockedIn) AS MinutesOff
    FROM @TimeSheetEntries ts
    INNER JOIN ClockData cd
        ON ts.StaffID = cd.StaffID
            AND ts.ClockedIn BETWEEN cd.EffectiveClockout AND dateadd(hour, 2, cd.EffectiveClockout)
)
SELECT *
FROM ClockData cd
WHERE NumClockIns = (SELECT MAX(NumClockIns) FROM ClockData WHERE ID = cd.ID)
```

This returns:

```
ID   StaffID   ClockedIn                 EffectiveClockout        NumClockIns   MinutesOff
3    5         2012-01-01 09:00:00.000   2012-01-01 12:00:00.000  1             0
4    5         2012-01-01 14:09:00.000   2012-01-01 17:30:00.000  1             0
1    4         2012-01-01 09:00:00.000   2012-01-01 19:30:00.000  3             150
```

**UPDATE**

In case it isn't clear, the MinutesOff is only the 'allowance' time, or the amount of time 'eaten' between the ClockedIn and EffectiveClockout shown in the same row. So, StaffID 5 took 129 minutes off between clocked time periods, but no allowance time, so MinutesOff is 0 for both rows.

Comment: As a matter of fact, your solution doesn't have higher requirements than Jeremy's with regard to the version of SQL Server: his requires SQL Server 2005 or later too, because it uses CTEs and references them multiple times (thus the CTEs couldn't be rewritten as plain nested subselects instead). Anyway, it's good that between you two at least one mentioned the minimum required version. :)

Comment: Thank you to @Dominic P and all others who have obviously gone to a great deal of trouble to answer the question. I've implemented Dominic's approach and it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there's less complicated ways to do this, but I was able to pull it off with a couple of CTEs:

```
declare @TimeSheetEntries table
    (
    ID int identity not null primary key,
    StaffID int not null,
    ClockedIn datetime not null,
    ClockedOut datetime not null
    );

insert into @TimeSheetEntries
    (
    StaffID,
    ClockedIn,
    ClockedOut
    )
select
    4,
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00',
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00'
union all select
    4,
    '2012-01-01 13:30:00',
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00'
union all select
    5,
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00',
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00'
union all select
    5,
    '2012-01-01 14:09:00',
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00'
union all select 
    4, 
    '2012-01-01 18:30:00', 
    '2012-01-01 19:30:00'       
;
with MultiCheckins as (
    select distinct
        StaffID,
        cast(cast(cast(ClockedIn as float) as int) as datetime) as TimeSheetDate,
        rank() over (
            partition by StaffID, 
            cast(cast(cast(ClockedIn as float) as int) as datetime)
            order by ClockedIn
            ) as ordinal,
        ClockedIn,
        ClockedOut
    from @TimeSheetEntries
), Organized as
(
select
    row_number() over (
        order by
            mc.StaffID,
            mc.TimeSheetDate,
            mc.ClockedIn,
            mc.ClockedOut
            ) as RowID,
    mc.StaffID,
    mc.TimeSheetDate,
    case
        when datediff(hour, coalesce(mc3.ClockedOut, mc.ClockedIn), mc.ClockedIn) >= 2
            then mc.ClockedIn 
        else coalesce(mc3.ClockedIn, mc.ClockedIn)
        end as ClockedIn,
    case 
        when datediff(hour, mc.ClockedOut, coalesce(mc2.ClockedIn, mc.ClockedOut)) < 2
            then coalesce(mc2.ClockedOut, mc.ClockedOut)
        else mc.ClockedOut
        end as ClockedOut
from
    MultiCheckins as mc
left outer join
    MultiCheckIns as mc3
        on mc3.StaffID = mc.StaffID
        and mc3.TimeSheetDate = mc.TimeSheetDate
        and mc3.ordinal =  mc.ordinal - 1
left outer join 
    MultiCheckIns as mc2
        on mc2.StaffID = mc.StaffID
        and mc2.TimeSheetDate = mc.TimeSheetDate
        and mc2.ordinal = mc.ordinal + 1
)
select distinct
    o.StaffID,
    o.ClockedIn,
    o.ClockedOut
from Organized as o
where
    not exists (
        select null from Organized as o2
        where o2.RowID <> o.RowID
        and o2.StaffID = o.StaffID
        and 
            (
            o.ClockedIn between o2.ClockedIn and o2.ClockedOut
            and o.ClockedOut between o2.ClockedIn and o2.ClockedOut
            )
        )
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to handle a staff member who clocks out more than once for a brief period, e.g. lunch and dinner.

Comment: @user92546: how doesn't it?  it returns the exact same results you wanted to see.  Please describe a situation it does not cover.

Comment: Try adding `union all select 4, '2012-01-01 18:30:00', '2012-01-01 19:30:00'` to the sample data.

Comment: Well that was outside the scope of your requirements, but here you go.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: definitely simpler.  More performant?  I don't even want to think about benchmarking that on large datasets.

Comment: There are many cases where cursors are faster. Running totals, for example, is much cheaper using a cursor than a self-join, *especially* at larger data sets, since the cost of the self-join grows non-linearly. Don't be fooled by the myth that cursors are always slower than a complex set-based alternative.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I was not disagreeing with you, per se.  There are times when cursors are more efficient - but in my experience, it's not often.  The resources and the locks can be annoying to deal with too.  All of this is moot, however... I don't feel like trying to benchmark this to see what would be faster.

Comment: I only suggested it because that's a massive, very complex query that the OP may not fully understand. If they need to tweak it in a week, they may not be able to. In other words, I was just commenting that they may be better off with the cursor. (Also resources and locking can be controlled when using cursors - they just usually aren't because people are lazy.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I won't argue the point, especially because in the context of this problem I think you may be right.  Still, that wasn't what OP asked for, and I considered this to be an interesting thought experiment.

Comment: Well I was going to suggest "just keep your cursor" in an answer, but I don't see what's wrong with having a discussion about it in the comments instead. The "right answer" is not always what the OP came here thinking he/she was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 :
Maybe insert it into a temp table and then use a left join to build a results table (if they can only clock in and out twice during the day this will work if you have 3 results it will not)

```
select *
from timesheet ts
left join timesheet tss on tss.id = ts.id
```

After this you can just get the min and max or even have a more robust report.

Option 2 :

```
create #TimeTable Table (UserID int, InTime int, OutTime int)

insert into #TimeTable (UserID) select distinct StaffID

Update #TimeTable set InTime = (select Min(InTime) from #TimeTable where StaffID = s.StaffID)  from #TimeTAble s

Update #TimeTable set OutTime = (Select Max(OutTime) from #TimeTable where StaffID = s.StaffID) from #TimeTable s
```

Given mroe time i'd merge these into two quick queries but three would work for not worrying about performance.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  There's no limit to the number of clockings so Option 1 won't work.
The problem with Option 2 is that is doesn't take account of the allowance of <= 2 hours to be off-site.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I know you can do this with a couple queries without doing it in a cursor though...  And it can be done with checking the times against each other.  Flagging it on that first pass then in the next query at least clean up what the first query did.  This would avoid having to loop in some sense.

Answer (score 0):

An iterative set-based approach:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @TimesheetEntries as Table ( Id Int Identity, StaffId Int, ClockIn DateTime, ClockOut DateTime )
insert into @TimesheetEntries ( StaffId, ClockIn, ClockOut ) values
  ( 4, '2012-05-03 09:00', '2012-05-03 12:00' ),
  ( 4, '2012-05-03 13:30', '2012-05-03 17:30' ), -- This falls within 2 hours of the next two rows.
  ( 4, '2012-05-03 17:35', '2012-05-03 18:00' ),
  ( 4, '2012-05-03 19:00', '2012-05-03 19:30' ),
  ( 4, '2012-05-03 19:45', '2012-05-03 20:00' ),
  ( 5, '2012-05-03 09:00', '2012-05-03 12:00' ),
  ( 5, '2012-05-03 14:09', '2012-05-03 17:30' ),
  ( 6, '2012-05-03 09:00', '2012-05-03 12:00' ),
  ( 6, '2012-05-03 13:00', '2012-05-03 17:00' )
select Id, StaffId, ClockIn, ClockOut from @TimesheetEntries

-- Find all of the periods that need to be coalesced and start the process.
declare @Bar as Table ( Id Int Identity, StaffId Int, ClockIn DateTime, ClockOut DateTime )
insert into @Bar
  select TSl.StaffId, TSl.ClockIn, TSr.ClockOut
    from @TimesheetEntries as TSl inner join
      -- The same staff member and the end of the left period is within two hours of the start of the right period.
      @TimesheetEntries as TSr on TSr.StaffId = TSl.StaffId and DateDiff( ss, TSl.ClockOut, TSr.ClockIn ) between 0 and 7200

-- Continue coalescing periods until we run out of work.
declare @Changed as Bit = 1
while @Changed = 1
  begin
  set @Changed = 0
  -- Coalesce periods.
  update Bl
    -- Take the later   ClockOut   time from the two rows.
    set ClockOut = case when Br.ClockOut >= Bl.ClockOut then Br.ClockOut else Bl.ClockOut end
    from @Bar as Bl inner join
      @Bar as Br on Br.StaffId = Bl.StaffId and
        -- The left row started before the right and either the right period is completely contained in the left or the right period starts within two hours of the end of the left.
        Bl.ClockIn < Br.ClockIn and ( Br.ClockOut <= Bl.ClockOut or DateDiff( ss, Bl.ClockOut, Br.ClockIn ) < 7200 )
  if @@RowCount > 0
    set @Changed = 1
  -- Delete rows where one period is completely contained in another.
  delete Br
    from @Bar as Bl inner join
      @Bar as Br on Br.StaffId = Bl.StaffId and
        ( ( Bl.ClockIn < Br.ClockIn and Br.ClockOut <= Bl.ClockOut ) or ( Bl.ClockIn <= Br.ClockIn and Br.ClockOut < Bl.ClockOut ) )
  if @@RowCount > 0
    set @Changed = 1
  end

-- Return all of the coalesced periods ...
select StaffId, ClockIn, ClockOut, 'Coalesced Periods' as [Type]
  from @Bar
union all
-- ... and all of the independent periods.
select StaffId, ClockIn, ClockOut, 'Independent Period'
  from @TimesheetEntries as TS
  where not exists ( select 42 from @Bar where StaffId = TS.StaffId and ClockIn <= TS.ClockIn and TS.ClockOut <= ClockOut )
order by ClockIn, StaffId
```

I'm sure that there are some optimizations that ought to be made.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this pretty easily with just a left join back to itself and a one-off match. The following is not a full implementation, but more of a proof of concept:

```
create table #TimeSheetEntries 
    ( 
    ID int identity not null primary key, 
    StaffID int not null, 
    ClockedIn datetime not null, 
    ClockedOut datetime not null 
    ); 

insert into #TimeSheetEntries 
    ( 
    StaffID, 
    ClockedIn, 
    ClockedOut 
    ) 
select 
    4, 
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00', 
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00' 
union all select 
    4, 
    '2012-01-01 13:30:00', 
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00' 
union all select 
    5, 
    '2012-01-01 09:00:00', 
    '2012-01-01 12:00:00' 
union all select 
    5, 
    '2012-01-01 14:09:00', 
    '2012-01-01 17:30:00'
union all select
    4,
    '2012-01-01 18:30:00', 
    '2012-01-01 19:30:00'
union all select 4, '2012-01-01 18:30:00', '2012-01-01 19:30:00';


select * from #timesheetentries tse1
left outer join #timesheetentries tse2 on tse1.staffid = tse2.staffid 
  and tse2.id = 
  (
      select MAX(ID) 
      from #timesheetentries ts_max 
      where ts_max.id < tse1.id and tse1.staffid = ts_max.staffid
  )
  outer apply   
  (
  select DATEDIFF(minute, tse2.clockedout, tse1.clockedin) as BreakTime
  ) as breakCheck

where BreakTime > 120 or BreakTime < 0 or tse2.id is null

order by tse1.StaffID, tse1.ClockedIn


   GO
   drop table #timesheetentries
   GO
```

The idea here is that you have your original timesheet table `tse1`, and then you do a `left join` to the same timesheet table, aliased as `tse2` and matching rows when `staffID` is the same and `tse2.ID` is the highest ID value that is still less than `tse1.ID`. This is clearly poor form - you'd probably want to use `ROW_NUMBER()` for this ID comparison, partitioned and ordered by `StaffID` and your `ClockedIn`/`ClockedOut` values, since times could have been input out of chronological order.

At this point, a row from the joined tables now contains time data from the current timesheet entry, as well as the one before it. This means that we can make a comparison between `ClockedIn`/`ClockedOut` values for consecutive time entries... and using `DATEDIFF()`, we can find out the length of time that a user has been away between their previous `Clockedout` and more recent `ClockedIn` values. I used an `OUTER APPLY` for this simply because it makes the code cleaner, but you could probably pack it into a subquery.

Once we do a `DATEDIFF()`, it's trivial to find cases where an individual's `BreakTime` does not exceed the 120-minute barrier and remove those timesheet entries, leaving only the significant rows of the employee's timesheet to be used in your later reporting.