# Group based on time difference between two date values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've searched around, but haven't been able to find anyone else with this same question.

I'm working with SQL Server (2008 R2).

Let's say I have the following three rows of data coming back from my query. What I need to do is group the first two rows into one (in either SQL Server or SSRS) based on the difference in minutes between the Start Time and the End Time (the Duration). How much time elapses between one row's End Time and the next row's Start Time is of no concern; I'm only looking at Duration.

Current result set:

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| Vehicle | Start Time | End Time   | Duration |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| 12      | 1:56:30 AM | 2:07:47 AM | 11       |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| 12      | 2:07:57 AM | 6:46:08 AM | 279      |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| 19      | 2:55:02 PM | 3:45:59 PM | 53       |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
```

Desired result set:

```
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| Vehicle | Start Time | End Time   | Duration |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| 12      | 1:56:30 AM | 6:46:08 AM | 290      |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
| 19      | 2:55:02 PM | 3:45:59 PM | 53       |
+---------+------------+------------+----------+
```

I feel like it has to be a matter of grouping, but I'm not sure how to group based on whether or not the start and end times are less than 15 minutes apart.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: A vaguely related question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10934821/92546).

Comment: With your 15 minutes part, are you saying that you want a <15 minute duration to always be rolled into the next matching vehicle row, or that any rows for the same vehicle that occur within 15 minutes of each other should be grouped together?

Comment: @iamdave Thanks for catching that and asking. It is simply based on the duration column. The amount of time that elapses between one row's end time and the next start time shouldn't be considered. I updated my question to be a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood your question, try this

```
Select Vehicle
      ,StartTime = min(StartTime)
      .EndTime   = max(EndTime)
      ,Duration  = sum(Duration)
From YourTable
Group By Vehicle
```

Comment: I don't think this takes into account the 15 minute window required to group rows together.  If the same vehicle is used on two different days for one hour each, you will get a duration many hours longer than it should be.